# Algorithm to generate graph of specific known form

Tags: graphs, tiling

I am trying to generate a graph (the structure with edges and nodes), that as a structure like an Order-7 triangular tiling of specified diameter around a central node.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-7_triangular_tiling

!http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-7_triangular_tiling#mediaviewer/File:H2_tiling_237-4.png

In this tiling, each node has 7 neighbors, and they tile nicely, forming triangles, a 2d hyperbolic space.

I am not looking for the specific example of order 7, but more trying to understand, how we can code neatly the generation.

I am also looking on how we can then make this graph 'spheric' (so that it folds upon itself, and every node has the same number of neighbors).

How would we do to tile hyperbolic 3d space with nodes with n neighbors forming a regular tetrahedron structures, (also folding upon itself in an 'hyperspheric' fashion)?

EDIT: By tiling nicely forming triangle (like in the picture), I mean, edges don't cross each other when represented in plane, the whole plane is filled, and faces are triangles. This graph is translation invariant and rotation invariant.

Comment: I edited my post. But I was just trying to describe the picture. The graph families I'm trying to generate are not random must be k regular,only have triangular faces, be translation invariant, and rotation invariant (by 2pi/7). These lattices seems to be described by a Wythoff symbol, I didn't understood wikipedia Wythoff construction. The structure is very regular, and I would be really surprised if the generating procedure was more than a few clever lines (maybe recursive), but I can't see them.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are the input and output of the algorithm you are looking for?

Comment: INPUT: the order of the graph here 7, the dimension of space, here surface of a sphere 2, the shape of the tiling face here triangle so 3, OUTPUT: a list of nodes, and for each node an ordered list of nodes, representing the edges. This graph must be of order specified and has lattice on a sphere properties,i.e. be translation and rotation invariant